# Overlapping points on a sphere and hemispheral shell

Tags: geometry

I have a hemispherical shell, with internal radius $r$, containing $n$ circular holes, each with radius $a$, distributed over it's surface, in such a way as to have $\frac{n}{3}$ in each $\frac{1}{3}$rd of the hemisphere (each labelled as a "ternary sector" for convenience). Underneath that hemisphere I have a sphere, with radius $r-x$ (where $0.01r < x < 0.1r$). The sphere and hemisphere remain a distance of $x$ apart at all times.

Given a pattern of holes on the hemisphere, a radius $r$ and a distance $x$, is it possible to calculate a pattern of $z$ non-overlapping spots (of the same area as the holes) on the sphere, where at least $3y$ spots (where $y$ is an integer) are located under the holes in the hemisphere, with $y$ spots in each ternary sector, no matter how the sphere is subsequently rotated?

For example, if this is possible, for the situation where y=2, a solution could look like:

- The fixed hemisphere containing 42 holes spread evenly across the surface of the hemisphere, with 14 holes in each "ternary" sector of the hemisphere.
- The sphere, separately containing a pattern of spots (which may or may not be evenly spaced), such that at least 6 spots in the top half of the sphere are located directly under 6 holes on the fixed hemisphere, with 2 of those holes being located in each "ternary sector" of the fixed hemisphere.
- Furthermore no matter how the sphere was subsequently rotated, this covering of spots by holes would always be true.

If this is not possible, that would also be good to know.

Comment: If the pattern is structured - projecting the pattern into the sphere could suffice - I think.

Comment: @Moti would that preserve the property of holes always lining up with points under rotation of the sphere? (specifically on the top portion of the sphere that is under the hemisphere)

Comment: What do you mean by "a pattern of $z$ points (of the same size as the holes)", how do points have size? Or do you mean $z$ holes? And what do you mean by "located under", if they are truly points this makes sense, but if they are holes do they need to be exactly under, or does there just need to be some overlap? Finally I can't understand your example at the end, would it be possible to sketch the pattern you describe and add it to the question in an edit?

Comment: @DavidSheard The points are fixed areas on the sphere of the same size as the holes. They need to be exactly under if possible. I used the word points primarily to differentiate them from the words holes (so I could refer to the two items separately), I didn't intend them to be interpreted as point structures (apologies for the confusion). I'll try do up a sketch tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Now I either think the answer is no, or I don't understand what you mean about invariance of the property under rotation. Here's why I think the answer is no. Holes and spots have positive area, and the (hemi)sphere has finite area, so there is only room for a finite number of holes and spots. As there are only finitely many spots, there are only finitely many orientations of the sphere under which the property holds (this set is discrete in $SO(3)$). Hence there is some small $\epsilon>0$ such that rotating by $\epsilon$ will miss-align all spots and holes.

Comment: @DavidSheard To be clear, it's not that specific holes and spots have to be aligned, but, using the example at the end, at least 2 spots in each sector need to be under 2 holes (but it can be more). If we rotate the sphere (even by a small amount) the original spots can fall out of alignment so long as others come into alignment. Furthermore, the pattern of spots does not have to, and my suspicion is cannot, be the same as the pattern of holes on the hemisphere.

Comment: What I'm thinking of is sort of analagous to the 2D case of two moire patterns that exhibit interference patterns at all points under rotation (even though there are only finitely many points/lines making up both pattern). Something similar to this (which is a moire pattern produced by two sheets of graphene and thus necessarily made up of elements of positive area): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern#/media/File:Graphene_moire_on_Ir(111)_-_schematic.svg

Comment: Obviously in my case I'm placing some more constraints on the system than the moire pattern (that the overlapping needs to occur in regular areas and be guaranteed to be of a particular size)

Comment: Ok, I understand you motivation better. In the case of Moiré patterns, generically none of the holes in the two planes are aligned (formally, the space of configurations of the two planes is the space of translations of the upper plane, which is $\mathbb{R}^2$. The set of translations for which at least one spot aligns with one holes is discrete/has measure 0 for the same reason as I outlined in my previous comment). As such I don't understand how you justify the third point in your example. How do you know such a pattern exists for $n=42$?

Comment: @DavidSheard I don't know a solution exists for $n=42$. The example at the end of the question is to give a less "symboly" representation of the problem, but is specifically caveated as only being potentially possible ("if this is possible" immediately after the "For example" is meant to show this is an illustrative example, not a specific  guaranteed to be correct example).

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify this point

Comment: In that case, I believe that it's not possible for the reason stated in my comment mention $SO(3)$. If you disagree with the argument, or want more details, let me know. What I suspect is true is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists an arrangement with $n$ sufficiently large and $r$ sufficiently small so that there is a pattern of spots with you desired property up to an allowable misalignment of $\epsilon$.